# What is the application of file ownership (chown) in linux?

Tags: users, group, chown

I have faced a problem in changing the permissions for a specific group of users in my system.

suppose I have four users u1,v1 and u2,v2 and two groups g1 and g2. u1,v1 are in g1 group and u2,v2 are in g2 group respectively.

Now I want a file which is "foo.bar" to be accessible(rwx) only by u1 in g1 group.  I typed the following for this purpose:

```
sudo chown u1:g1 foo.bar
sudo chmod 700 foo.bar
```

but I have the following questions:

**first.** What is the usage of giving a file ownership to a group where we can restrict other users using chmod command ?(the third field in file permissions rwx-rwx-**rwx** ) what is the application of chown here ?

let me give an example for this question: I only want "foo.bar" to be accessible from g1 users and not any users in the system. Can it be done just by using chown command ? if not what is its application !

**second.** how we can give specific permissions to a specific group ? for example I want g1 group to have only read permission on any files which is owned by it. so when I type the following in the terminal

```
sudo chown :g1 foo.bar
```

without any more commands, all the u1 and v1 users have only read permission on this file. is it possible only by chown ?

I hope I made my points clear to you all.

Comment: You first say that you want `foo.bar` to be accessible only by user `u1`, then you say you want it accessible by all users in group `g1`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, in both scenarios I only want to know the chown application ! I mean I can restrict users by only using chmod command. so why I need to use chown at all ?

Comment: Please don't cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079160/what-is-the-application-of-file-ownership-chown-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chown and chmod have two different purposes:

- `chown` defines who owns the file.
- `chmod` defines who can do what.

---

1. To restrict the access to a specific group: the group have to be owner of the file and the permission bits have to be set properly.

   ```
   sudo chown :g1 foo.bar && sudo chmod 770 foo.bar
   ```

   The 3 last permission bits are related to all other users: Chown command sets ownership. Users that are not owners will be concerned by those 3 last permission bits.
2. If you want to set specific permissions for a group that is the owner of the file: `sudo chmod 770 foo.bar`. This can also be set at file creation with [umask](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html).

Else, if you want different permissions for each group, you may want to have a look at ACL permissions. This will allow you to set for exemple `r--` for g1, `rwx` for g2 and `---` for others.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want a file which is `foo.bar` to be accessible(`rwx`) only by `u1` in `g1` group. I typed the following for this purpose:
>
> ```
> sudo chown u1:g1 foo.bar
> sudo chmod 700 foo.bar
> ```

This will give permissions on the file for user `u1` (only). The group you've set the file to doesn't really matter since members of the group don't have any permissions set. Or rather, they have exactly the same permissions as "others", so it doesn't matter if a given user access is determined by the "group" permissions or the "other" permissions.

Note that you can't directly require *both* the user and the group to match. The above file will be accessible to `u1` regardless of their group membership.

What you can do, is create a directory owned by e.g. `root.g1`, accessible only by user and group; and then a file within it that is owned by `u1` and accessible only by the user. This is most often done for e.g. crontabs, which are owned by a particular user, but should only be modified by a particular (setgid) tool. See e.g. `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` on any Debian/Ubuntu system.

> What is the usage of giving a file ownership to a group where we can restrict other users using chmod command ... I only want `foo.bar` to be accessible from `g1` users and not any [other] users in the system.

You set the file's group to `g1`, grant any access you like to the group. E.g. `chown a.g1 file && chmod 660 file` would only let user `a` and members of group `g1` read and write the file. (In addition, user `a` can change the permissions. If you want to prevent that, you'll need to make the file owned by some user that will not do that.)

> how we can give specific permissions to a specific group ? for example I want `g1` group to have only read permission on any files which is owned by it.

You can't. The permissions are a property of the file, not the user or group. In the above case, the file was given read/write permissions to the group, so that's what happens. You'll need to take care to not let any files have write permissions for the group, if that's what you want.

> [the question from the comment] `chown` is mainly used for giving ownership to a group so later we can limit the group users to the file by using `chmod` command yes? otherwise we can restrict all other users except the owner by using `chmod` alone and there is no need to use `chown`.

Well, pretty much. Of course, `root` can use `chown` to actually change the owning user too, if that's warranted. That will happen at least under the hood when creating a new user: the ownership of the home directory has to be set somehow.

(If the user's primary group is appropriate, you could have a use for `chmod` without `chown`, but that's just skipping an unnecessary `chown`.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your third paragraph was the thing I needed.  just one more thing to accept your response as answer. chown is mainly used for giving ownership to a group so later we can limit the group users to the file by using chmod command yes ? otherwise we can restrict all other users except the owner by using chmod alone and there is no need to use chown.

Comment: @PsP, well, pretty much. But if the default group is something like `users` that everyone is a member of, then you may want to change the group's access permissions too (or have a directory with `0700` permissions for any private files). I edited the answer a bit.